# SQL server delete all rows that have a duplicate (inclusive)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table named `Sales`:

```
+----------+-----------------+------------+
| Salesman | Sales Portfolio |   Month    |
+----------+-----------------+------------+
| Kavi     |           12500 | 2018-01-05 |
| Kavi     |           12500 | 2018-02-28 |
| Kavi     |           12500 | 2018-03-20 |
| Raj      |           21055 | 2018-01-05 |
| Raj      |           32015 | 2018-02-28 |
| Raj      |           12000 | 2018-03-20 |
+----------+-----------------+------------+
```

If a `Sales Portfolio` value is duplicated, remove all rows including itself from the table. In the example above, `12500` is duplicated, so remove all rows where `Sales Portfolio = 12500`.

Example expected output (only Raj displayed):
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to display your expected output, then try the following:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Salesman, [Sales Portfolio]) cnt
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    Salesman, [Sales Portfolio], Month
FROM cte
WHERE cnt = 1;
```

If you want to *delete* the non displaying records as well, then we can use the same CTE:

```
DELETE FROM cte WHERE cnt > 1;
```